# Why my program working only with pos or neg numbers?

Tags: assembly, x86, division, fasm

I need to write a dividing program which take 2 decimal numbers( they can be positive or negative) and show answer in binary code.

Program is working but only with pos or neg numbers. When I comment neg (under `NeNegSum`, I marked it) it works with neg numbers and with pos when it not commented. What I need to do, to make it working with all numbers ??

```x86
include 'win32ax.inc'
include 'input.inc'

.data
    num1 dd 0 
    num2 dd 0
    mes rb 100h
    Flag db 0
.code

start:
  input_dialog
  or eax, eax
  jz exit
  mov esi, eax
  call ASCIIToNum
  cmp [Flag],1
  jne .NeNeg
  ;neg eax
  mov [Flag],0
  .NeNeg:
  mov [num1], eax

  input_dialog
  ;mov ecx, 3
  or eax, eax
  jz exit
  mov esi, eax
  call ASCIIToNum
  cmp [Flag],1
  jne .NeNeg2
  ;neg eax
  mov [Flag],0
  .NeNeg2:
  mov [num2], eax
  div [num1]
  mov ebx,2

  lea esi, [mes+50]
  cmp eax,0
  jl .NeNegSumm
  neg eax
  mov [Flag],0
  .NeNegSumm:
  ;neg eax  ;<———this neg
  call NumToASCII
  cmp [Flag],1
  jne .Cout
  dec esi
  mov byte [esi],'-'
  .Cout:
  invoke  MessageBox, HWND_DESKTOP, esi, "Div is:", MB_OK
exit:
  invoke  ExitProcess,0
.end start

.input_resources

proc ASCIIToNum 
;local sum2 dd 0
  push ebx ecx
  xor eax,eax 
  xor ebx,ebx
  mov ecx, 10
  jmp .next
.next1:
  mov [Flag],1
  ;inc esi
.next: 
  mov bl, [esi]
  inc esi
  cmp bl,'-'
  je .next1

  cmp bl, ''
  or bl,bl 
  jz .done 
  sub bl, 30h 
  mul ecx 
  add eax,ebx 
  jmp .next 
.done: 
  pop ecx ebx
  ret
endp 

proc NumToASCII
;.sum2 rb 100
  push ecx edx
  mov byte [esi], 0 
  mov  ecx,2
.divloop:
  mov  edx, 0
  div  ecx
  add  dl, 30h
  dec  esi
  mov  [esi], dl
  or  eax, eax
  jnz  .divloop
  pop edx ecx  
  ret
endp
```

Comment: Your `.divloop:` should use `shr eax,1` instead of `div` by 2.  shift/mask is much more efficient than `div`.  Or to get the digits in printing order, rotate left so you get the top bit first.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the `DIV` instruction to calculate `num2 / num1`. `DIV` is used to divide **unsigned numbers**. If you need to divide **signed numbers** (positive and negative) then use the `IDIV` instruction.

Don't forget to sign-extend the dividend beforehand since `IDIV [num1]` actually performs `EDX:EAX / [num1]`.  (`cdq` sign-extends EAX into EDX:EAX, i.e. sets all bits of EDX to the sign bit of EAX.)

The quotient of this division is already a signed number. To decide about outputting the "-" character, you just look at the sign of the number in `EAX`.

Additional comments:

. It makes more sense to move the sign-related instructions to the *ASCIIToNum* conversion routine.

. The conversion to binary representation should not use a division by 2 (highly inefficient). It's easy to do this with a simple shift to the right.

. You can write this code without requiring a separate *Flag* variable. Instead save and restore the processor flags.

```
include 'win32ax.inc'
include 'input.inc'

.data
    num1 dd 0 
    num2 dd 0
    mes  rb 100h
.code

start:
  input_dialog
  test eax, eax
  jz   exit
  mov  esi, eax
  call ASCIIToNum
  mov  [num1], eax

  input_dialog
  test eax, eax
  jz   exit
  mov  esi, eax
  call ASCIIToNum
  mov  [num2], eax
  CDQ                  ;Sign-extend EAX into EDX:EAX
  IDIV  [num1]         ;Signed division of EDX:EAX by [num1]

  lea  esi, [mes+50]
  test eax, eax
  pushf
  jns  .Convert        ;Quotient was positive, no NEG needed
  neg  eax
.Convert:
  call NumToASCII
  popf
  jns  .Cout           ;Quotient was positive, no '-' needed
  dec  esi
  mov  byte [esi], '-'
.Cout:
  invoke  MessageBox, HWND_DESKTOP, esi, "Div is:", MB_OK
exit:
  invoke  ExitProcess,0
.end start

.input_resources

; Input: ESI
; Output: EAX
proc ASCIIToNum 
  push  ebx esi
  xor   eax, eax
  movzx ebx, byte [esi]
  cmp   bl, '-'
  pushf
  sete  bl             ;Number is positive, no unary '-' to skip
  add   esi, ebx
.next: 
  mov   bl, [esi]
  inc   esi
  test  bl, bl 
  jz    .done 
  sub   bl, 30h 
  imul  eax, 10
  add   eax, ebx 
  jmp   .next 
.done:
  popf
  jne   .pos           ;Number is positive, no NEG needed
  neg   eax
.pos:
  pop   esi ebx
  ret
endp 

; Input: EAX
; Output: ESI, EAX=0
proc NumToASCII
  push edx
  mov  byte [esi], 0 
.divloop:
  mov  dl, '0'
  shr  eax, 1
  adc  dl, 0
  dec  esi
  mov  [esi], dl
  test eax, eax
  jnz  .divloop
  pop  edx
  ret
endp
```

Comment: @peter cordes I was in the process of editing your edit back in. Seems like you just did the same thing.

Comment: Yup, I wasn't sure if you'd noticed / cared about my edit or not, so I redid it after your big edit stepped on it.  I wish SO had an option to merge conflicting edits instead of being basically forced to step on them :/